# Enabling Proxy server using Powershell remoting

Tags: powershell, proxy, powershell-remoting

I am trying to add a Proxy server to a remote server(ServerB) using PowerShell Remoting. However each time, the proxy is cleared after being set. Below is the code which I use:

```
Invoke-command -computername ServerB -authentication Negotiate -scriptblock{$regKey="HKCU:\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Internet Settings"
$proxyServer = ""
$proxyServerToDefine = 'our.proxy.server:port'

$proxyServer = Get-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyServer -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
if([string]::IsNullOrEmpty($proxyServer))
{
    Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyServer -value $proxyServerToDefine
    Set-ItemProperty -path $regKey ProxyEnable -value 1

    #The only way I've found to get the proxy settings to apply is to start ie in some way.
        $ie = New-Object -ComObject internetexplorer.application
        $ie.Quit()

    Remove-Variable -Name ie
    
    Write-Verbose "Proxy is now enabled"
}
else
{
    Write-Verbose "Proxy Server already present"
}
}
```

The proxy is being cleared after I have instantiated the 'ie' object.
I have tried to enable the Proxy by running the above code(proxy enable code section) inside PowerShell remote session(using `Enter-PSSession`), however this has not resolved my issue.

Above code works fine for me if I login to the server and runs it from there.

Comment: I have noticed that you are setting proxy using HKCU:, have you tried setting proxy in HKLM: ? Depending on you profile settings and Group Policies HKCU: setting could only last for the duration of you remote session.